# How can I add a dynamic list of CSS classes to a div using 2sxc and a c# razor template?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

This is mainly a C# Razor question but I included details to help understand the issue. Basically, I want to assign a bunch of CSS classes to cards in a listing in a 2sxc App.

Using 2sxc App, I have a listing of "Careers" that display a title and a picture. I also have a sidebar that has filter buttons so users can filter the results. They would filter on "school category" or "province", for example.

I'm using a c# razor template to output this list of careers. I'm also using a javascript called MixItUp to sort and filter the list. MixItUp expects that I assign CSS classes in the HTML to each career card so it knows what to filter. In my 2sxc App, I have a content type called "Career" and then another content type called "School Category". In the Career content type, I have an entity field for the School Category so I can assign multiple school categories to each career.

The issue I'm having is in my C# razor template: In my career card listing loop, I created another loop to get the school categories. It looks like this:

```
if (career.Categories.Count > 0) {
   foreach(var schoolCategory in AsList(career.Categories as object)){
            @Html.Raw(".filter-" + schoolCategory.SchoolCategory.ToLower().Replace(" ","-") + " ")
    }
```

}

But I don't know how I can take the results of this code and add it to the career card div? I tried different things like making the for-each part a variable but I can't seem to use this variable outside of the loop for use in the outer template.

How could I assign these classes in this case?

Answer (score 1):

BTW: You should also be able to do the same using Linq and string.join - ca. like this

@{
var schoolFilter = string.Join(" ", AsList(carrer.Categories as Object)
.Select(c => "filter-" + c.SchoolCategory.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-"));
}

Answer (score 0):

My friend / developer helped troubleshoot and we found the answer.

```
var schoolFilter = "";
if (career.Categories.Count > 0) {
   foreach(var schoolCategory in AsList(career.Categories as object)){
        schoolFilter += "filter-" + schoolCategory.SchoolCategory.ToLower().Replace(" ","-") + " ";
    }} 
<div class="mix @schoolFilter">card</div>
```